# Run query against each DB

Tags: php

Im using php to do this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($db_list)) {
 echo $row->Database . "<br>";
```

}

DB1
DB2
DB3
DB4

I want to add to this by adding a simple select query and running that against each database. the select will pull out the firstname of every user in the users table from each DB.

Comment: I get suspicious when a question doesn't have any question marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
(SELECT username, 'DB1' AS Database FROM DB1.users)
UNION ALL
(SELECT username, 'DB2' AS Database FROM DB2.users)
UNION ALL
...etc
```

Changed `UNION`s to `UNION ALL`

Comment: Don't use UNION, use UNION ALL